# Goals from AdWords Campaigns

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have about 10 different AdWords campaigns setup to send the user to a form I made. When the user submits this form they're taken to a unique thank you page.

I created a new destination goal in Analytics that tracks whenever a user lands on this unique thank you page. This seems to be working, but the problem is I don't know what campaign is performing best to track conversions.

I'd like to track which AdWord campaign was most effective in sending the user to the thank you page (completed the form)

I was hoping to create a pie chart (custom dashboard) in Analytics showing me the top performing "slices".

I created it by making a pie chart, over the past 4 months of data, and I said group by AdWords Campaign Id (I also tried Campaign, and Campaign id dimensions) but in all cases, it just shows me "not set" as the Adword campaign id, and I don't see any of my other campaign ids. coming up in the list. That seems incorrect as I know people have submitted the form.

If I go to AdWords, I do see traffic and I can see what is redirecting the user to the form itself, so I know it's working, but I now want to see of that traffic, who completes.

Any suggestions for how to do this? Maybe I need to step back or I missed a critical step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking your auto-tagging settings within Google AdWords, and making sure you've linked your Analytics account views with your Google Analytics account.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1733663?hl=en